# Ansible Vault - .json not unencrypted

Tags: json, encryption, ansible, ansible-vault

I have a .json file which I have successfully encrypted with ansible vault:

```
{
  "database": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "host": "127.0.0.1:3306",
    "name": "database"
  }
}
```

Encrypted with: `ansible-vault encrypt config.json`

Run ansible playbook with: `ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass`

Enter the same password and the playbook runs but the files aren't unencrypted on the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your playbook/role?

Comment: Look more detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773294/how-to-upload-encrypted-file-using-ansible-vault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't simply encrypt files and then transfer them over.  There are a few [github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7298) [issues](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/8110) about this, but ultimately the solution is that you have to store encrypted contents of a file in a variable or use the `lookup` plugin to get the file contents and put them remotely.

The encrypted variable should be self-explanatory.  Here's a quick example of using the lookup plugin:

```
- copy: 
    content: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/deepest/darkest/secrets') }}" 
    dest: /remote/unencrypted/destination
```