# Decrypting ansible vault files before rsyncing

Tags: encryption, ansible, ansible-vault

I encrypted a bunch of files (certificates) using the following script

```
for i in $(find . -type f); do ansible-vault encrypt $i  --vault-password-file ~/.vault && echo $i encrypted ; done
```

During rsyncing I run something like this

```
- name: Copy letsencrypt files 
  synchronize:
   src: "{{ path }}/letsencrypt/"
   dest: /etc/letsencrypt/
   rsync_path: "sudo rsync"
   rsync_opts:
    - "--delete"
    - "--checksum"
    - "-a"
  notify:
   - Reload Nginx
```

The problem I’ve faced is that the files that moved still remained encrypted. I thought ansible was smart enough to detect if it was encrypted and decrypt like how I do here

```
- name: Copy deploy private key
  copy:
    content: "{{ private_key_content }}"
    dest: "/home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa"
    owner: deploy
    group: deploy
    mode: 0600
  no_log: true
```

Back to the earlier question, how do I make sure the files in the folder/files are **decrypted before rsyncing**?

**Edit:**

I tried using the [copy module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37487382/113247) since it is encryption aware but the module seems to be hanging. Noticed some issues with copy module for directories on [ansible github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16929) and I am back to synchronize.

I also tried the [with_fileglob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696952/copy-multiple-files-with-ansible) approach but that flattens the directory structure.

**Edit 2:**

I got encryption, decryption to work with the copy module but its horribly slow.

Answer (score 3):

There is already an issue https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/45161 at the ansible site open and the conclusion is:

```
Synchronize is a wrapper around rsync, I doubt that you can hook into the
process like that. You might want to implement a custom module doing this
or use something, which supports it.
```